# SQL joins with multiple records into one with a default

Tags: sql

My 'people' table has one row per person, and that person has a division (not unique) and a company (not unique).

I need to join people to p_features, c_features, d_features on:

```
people.person=p_features.num_value  
people.division=d_features.num_value  
people.company=c_features.num_value
```

... in a way that if there is a record match in p_features/d_features/c_features only, it would be returned, but if it was in 2 or 3 of the tables, the most specific record would be returned.

From my test data below, for example, query for person=1 would return
'FALSE'
 person 3 returns maybe, person 4 returns true, and person 9 returns default

The biggest issue is that there are 100 features and I have queries that need to return all of them in one row. My previous attempt was a function which queried on feature,num_value in each table and did a foreach, but 100 features * 4 tables meant 400 reads and it brought the database to a halt it was so slow when I loaded up a few million rows of data.

```
create table p_features (
        num_value int8,
        feature varchar(20),
        feature_value varchar(128)
);
create table c_features (
        num_value int8,
        feature varchar(20),
        feature_value varchar(128)
);
create table d_features (
        num_value int8,
        feature varchar(20),
        feature_value varchar(128)
);
create table default_features (
        feature varchar(20),
        feature_value varchar(128)
);
create table people (
        person int8 not null,
        division int8 not null,
        company int8 not null
);
insert into people values (4,5,6);
insert into people values (3,5,6);
insert into people values (1,2,6);
insert into p_features values (4,'WEARING PANTS','TRUE');
insert into c_features values (6,'WEARING PANTS','FALSE');
insert into d_features values (5,'WEARING PANTS','MAYBE');
insert into default_features values('WEARING PANTS','DEFAULT');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transpose the features into rows with a ranking. Here I used a common-table expression. If your database product does not support them, you can use temporary tables to achieve the same effect.

```
;With RankedFeatures As
    (
    Select 1 As FeatureRank, P.person, PF.feature, PF.feature_value
    From people As P
        Join p_features As PF
            On PF.num_value = P.person
    Union All
    Select 2, P.person, PF.feature, PF.feature_value
    From people As P
        Join d_features As PF
            On PF.num_value = P.division
    Union All
    Select 3, P.person, PF.feature, PF.feature_value
    From people As P
        Join c_features As PF
            On PF.num_value = P.company
    Union All
    Select 4, P.person, DF.feature, DF.feature_value
    From people As P
        Cross Join default_features As DF
    )
    , HighestRankedFeature As
    (
    Select Min(FeatureRank) As FeatureRank, person
    From RankedFeatures
    Group By person
    )
Select RF.person, RF.FeatureRank, RF.feature, RF.feature_value
From people As P
    Join HighestRankedFeature As HRF
        On HRF.person = P.person
    Join RankedFeatures As RF
        On RF.FeatureRank = HRF.FeatureRank
            And RF.person = P.person
Order By P.person
```

Comment: This is awesome. I don't have common tables in Informix so I made RankedFeatures a view and everything works perfectly. Thank you very much for your effort!

Comment: One more thing, since if I have 5 features, I have 5 rows, can I make a view of this into a horizonal view such as:

select person, (value when feature='WEARING PANTS'), (value when feature='WEARING HAT'), etc from your table above.. hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I had understood very well your question, but to use JOIN, you need your table loaded already and then use the **SELECT** statement with **INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN** or whatever you need to show.
If you post some more information, maybe turn it easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There are some aspects of your schema I'm not understanding, like how to relate to the `default_features` table if there's no match in any of the specific tables. The only possible join condition is on `feature`, but if there's no match in the other 3 tables, there's no value to join on. So, in my example, I've hard-coded the DEFAULT since I can't think of how else to get it.

Hopefully this can get you started and if you can clarify the model a bit more, the solution can be refined.

```
select p.person, coalesce(pf.feature_value, df.feature_value, cf.feature_value, 'DEFAULT')
    from people p
        left join p_features pf
            on p.person = pf.num_value
        left join d_features df
            on p.division = df.num_value
        left join c_features cf
            on p.company = cf.num_value
```